# How do I specify the compression type in zlib?

Tags: python, zlib, huffman-code

I have this code which uses zlib to compresses a binary string:

```
f = open("compressed.bin", "wb")
x = zlib.compress(b"Some text to be compressed")
f.write(x)
f.close()
```

The data always gets compressed with fixed Huffman codes, regardless of the input string, whereas I want the data to be compressed with dynamic Huffman codes. I even tried using a string with several repetitions (such as 100 'A's, followed by 100 'B's, followed by 100 'A's, and so on) but it also ends up compressed with fixed codes.

**Edit:** the result is the same if I specify `level=9`.

How do I specify that the data should be compressed with dynamic codes regardless of which method achieves better compression?

Comment: You could create compression object using zlib.compressobj; however, this presently supports only DEFLATE compression method but you would be able to pass other arguments and modify the compression parameters.

Comment: I am actually behind DEFLATE compression, so does it have an option for forcing dynamic encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it more data. At least a few 10's of K.

Fixed coding is only used when a fixed block would be smaller than a dynamic block for the same data. That is generally only the case when a small amount of data is being compressed, or for the last deflate block where only a small amount of data remains.